# Mate/Caja: Disabling recursive file search in caja's "open/save file" dialogs

Tags: mate-desktop, caja

I'm using **Ubuntu Mate 19.04 Disco**, using **MATE Caja 1.20.3**.

Recently after a system update (think from **18.10** to **19.04**) the behavior of the open file/close file GTK dialogs changed:

When I typed something previously there, it searched within the local directory and that only.

Now it searches recursively, annoyingly not even displaying local matches on the very top and it annoys me tremendously.

However, I do not know what this official "deep search" feature is called so I cannot seem to find the correct terms to disable it.

What is this called and how can I shut it off?

Comment: Don't know if it's possible to disable it, but, as an alternative, you can search in just the current directory using the Ctrl-S hotkey inside Caja, as discussed at https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/search-with-wildcards/.

Comment: The shortcut for GTK file chooser is `/` or CTRL+L